# Resizable and collabsable gridColumn with gridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, togglebutton, gridsplitter

I'd Like to have a Sidebar which can be hidden by pressing a ToggleButton and re-sized by the user via Mouse using a GridSplitter Control. In the end I'd like it to look like this:

(Please look at Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcHHB.png) )

And:

(Please look at Picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5c0y.png) )

This is what i have so far:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="4"
 BorderThickness="1,0" Foreground="{x:Null}" Background="#01000000" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ColorControlBorder}"/>
<Grid x:Name="grid" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4,0,0,0" Background="{DynamicResource IconErrorFilter}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Expander x:Name="expander2" Style="{DynamicResource AddExpanderStyle}" 
        ExpandDirection="Up" Background="#D8FFFFFF" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ColorControlBorder}"
        DataContext="{Binding FilterTypesPMod}" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Expander.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CollectionFilterTypes" Source="{Binding FilterTypes}">
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <ComponentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Order" Direction="Ascending" />
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Expander.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <ItemsControl BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionFilterTypes}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Bla... />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource CollapsingToggleButtonStyle}" Background="{DynamicResource ColorMainForeground}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <ToggleButton.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </ToggleButton.LayoutTransform>
</ToggleButton>
```

When I use it without the GridSplitter it is working fine (except the resizing): When I press the ToggleButton the content of the Grid 'grid' dissapears and the GridColumn(1) gets smaller leaving more space for GridColumn(0). But as soon as I put in the GridSplitter the automated resizing stops. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Need more details to be of any help. 1. A lot of your styles are missing. What are you doing when toggle button is pressed? As this might be a trivial probelm, it will be best if you can upload a small sample reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're having the same problem as in this question:

[GridSplitter disables my RowDefinition style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234888)

As akjoshi has explained the GridSplitter changes the Height property of rows (Width property of columns). If you check the value source for the Height or Width property after the GridSplitter has been used to resize a row or column, you'll see it's been set to "local". "Local" values override any values set by styles, templates or triggers. Clearing the Height or Width property allows the Height or Width property to again be set using triggers and/or styles.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario and looks like I understood whats happening in your case. Here's what your problem is -

If you just use `ToggleButton` then your column would expand/collapse correctly;
if you use `GridSplitter`, then it would expand/collapse correctly too;
but if you use `GridSplitter` and then try and use `ToggleButton`
then the column won't shrink correctly.

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/akjoshi/External/GridSplitterDemo.xaml.txt) is xaml I used to replicate the issue.

The reason is that once you use `GridSplitter`, it changes the width of the column to a fixed value, due to which <`ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>` doesn't hold true anymore; it is changed to a fixed value `<ColumnDefinition Width="154"/>`. Now even if content inside that column is collapsed the column width remains fixed(i.e. 154). This can easily be verified using SNOOP.

One solution to this is to change the width of your second column to `Auto` when ToggleButton is pressed (either through animation or code); It's not straight forward to set the width of a column through animation but some workarounds(creating `GridLengthAnimation` ) are available as explained in these SO questions -

[Grid Column changing Width when animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242072/grid-column-changing-width-when-animating)

[In WPF, has anybody animated a Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197855/in-wpf-has-anybody-animated-a-grid)

Comment: At the moment I'm pretty busy with other stuff but I take a look at it ass soon as possible (Probably start of next week) But thank you for answering me... And you are right; I forgot to post all the styletriggers: I'll add them as soon as possible...

Comment: Let us know about your findings and posting your solution will be great.